# problem setting up multidimensional array and using .push()

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to setup a multidimensional array where I can push value into it where it needs to.

For example, I have a `cacheArray = new Array(col0Array, col1Array, col2Array);` which would accessible using `cacheArray[0]` etc...

Now, in a loop I would check `cacheArray[column_number].length`, which would be the length of whichever `colArray`. Depending on that I want to `cacheArray[column_number].push("my_class");`

My intention is to add the css class name to the sub column arrays, and check the previous value in the sub array for that column so I can get a checkered colour effect. But pushing like I did gives me an error: `cacheArray[column_number].push` is not a function.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear how you initialize your data structure.  This will initialize an array of three columns where each column is itself an array:

```
var cacheArray = [[], [], []];
```

You can then push values into each of those subarrays:

```
cacheArray[0].push("my_class");
cacheArray[0].push("his_class");
cacheArray[0].push("nobodys_class");
cacheArray[1].push("their_class");
cacheArray[2].push("your_class");
```

That would result in this data structure for `cacheArray`:

```
[["my_class", "his_class", "nobodys_class"], ["their_class"], ["your_class"]];
```

In a modern browser, you can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/f9hy4/.  I say modern browser just because the sample code requires `JSON.stringify()` to visualize the results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something but if you are initialising a multi (as opposed to a two) dimensional array, then cacheArray[column_number].push would not exist as a function because you are only providing one of the dimensions.

cacheArray[column_number].push("my_class") would work if you initialised a two dimensional array because you would be pushing on to the array that is at cacheArray[column_number]. Thus if column_number was 1, and this was the first item you had pushed cacheArray[1][0] would equal "my_class".

I can't help thinking there is an easier way to do this anyway, perhaps an array of objects which could hold the last and current values for each column?

Answer (score 0):

You have declare your array `cacheArray` as single dimensional make it as two dimensional array by initialize it.
you are actually pushing a new value to the `cacheArray[column_number][some_index]` that is doesn't exits, this statement indicate that you are pushing a `my_class` in the index `cacheArray[column_number][some_index]` that is not present, that's why it gives error.

you may try this:
`cacheArray = new Array(col0Array, col1Array, col2Array);

for(var i = 0, i = cacheArray.length; i++)`

`cacheArray[i] = new Array();

cacheArray[column_number].push("my_class");`